# Laravel leftJoin AS

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

How can I make that query in Laravel Eloquent or Fluent?

```
DUELS
|id|userId1    | UserId2
-------------------------
|1|       1    |  4     |
|2|       3    |  2     |
|3|       2    |  1     |
-------------------------

USERS
|id| firstName | 
----------------
|1|    Bob     |  
|2|    Hans    | 
|3|    Jerome  | 
|3|    Katy    | 
----------------
```

Query: get the names of the users in the duels where the user with $userId is participating:

```
SELECT u1.firstName AS user1FirstName, u2.firstName AS user2FirstName
    FROM duels             
    LEFT JOIN users AS u1                 
        ON userId1 = u1.id         
    LEFT JOIN users AS u2    
        ON userId2 = u2.id           
    WHERE userId1 = $userId || userId2 = $userId
```

Comment: Can you have _competition_  in this situation so as to know what competition is between the users?

Comment: Sorry I don´t understand what you mean.

Comment: I mentioned that to make sure that there is a _competition_ between two users (which is in fact a duel). Did you try the approaches I've mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ***Laravel's Fluent***, to perform that query you need to do the following:

```
DB::table('users')->join('duels', function($join) use ($userId){
     $join->on('users.id', '=', 'duels.userId1')
          ->orOn('users.id', '=', 'duels.userId2')
          ->where('users.id', '=', $userId);
})->get();
```

Using ***Laravel's Eloquent***, however, you may consider the user as either ***first player***, or as ***second player***. 
In your `User` model, define the above two relationships as such:

```
     class User extends Eloquent{

        /**
         * ...
         */

         public function duelsAsFirstPlayer(){
             return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\User', 'duels', 'user_id_1', 'user_id_2');
         }

         public function duelsAsSecondPlayer(){
             return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\User', 'duels', 'user_id_2', 'user_id_1');
         }    
     }
```

Now, in order to get *all the users the user with `$userId` has duels with*, query the `User` model as such:

as **first player**:

```
$users = App\User::find($userId)->duelsAsFirstPlayer()->get();
```

or as **second player**:

```
$users = App\User::find($userId)->duelsAsSecondPlayer()->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i really wanted to get all duels where the user is participating with one query :)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to query two sides of a relation (either if it's one-to-many or many-to-many) _in one shot_ using the **Eloquent** approach (and display in a tabular form). Because the user will be participating either as _user 1_ or _user 2_ you'll HAVE TO take that into consideration while querying the Eloquent relationship. Although, using raw queries, you can display the result as a table mapping user duels.